# How to display variable data in PDF when using syncfusion pdf creator?

Tags: flutter, pdf, syncfusion

I'm building a Flutter web app targeting Chrome that needs to build PDFs, so I'm using [SyncFusion's Flutter PDF package](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf).

Problem is that I cannot get variable data to display inside the PDF reports I create.  Can you help me?

Here's my code: (no errors or warnings)

```
Future<void> createHoursReportPdf(DateTime reportDate) async {

int yearWeek = getYearWeekNumber(widget.selectedDate);
String reportTitle = "Hours Report for $yearWeek";
print(reportTitle);

// Create a PDF document.
PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();

// Add a page and draw text
document.pages.add().graphics.drawString(
    reportTitle,
    PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.helvetica, 20),
    brush: PdfSolidBrush(PdfColor(0, 0, 0)),
    bounds: const Rect.fromLTWH(20, 60, 150, 30));

// Save the document
List<int> bytes = await document.save();

// Dispose the document
document.dispose();

// Download the output file - Requires import 'dart:html';
AnchorElement(
    href:
    "data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,${base64.encode(bytes)}")
  ..setAttribute("download", "output_$yearWeek.pdf")    // I wonder if there's a way to just display
  ..click();
```

}

The console output is:

```
Hours Report for 202405
```

Then it creates a PDF, but the PDF does not include the $yearWeek variable data.  It only says: "Hours Report for ".  See image:

[image: PDF is missing variable data and I don't know why.]

Why doesn't this code include the "202405" that's in the console?

```
document.pages.add().graphics.drawString(
    reportTitle
```

Thank you for your help!

Note: This is a stateful widget page. I can get something like this to work in a stateless widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounds are the problem,

```
bounds: const Rect.fromLTWH(20, 60, 150, 300));
```

React.fromLTWH indicates Left, Top, Width and Height. You didn't have enough space to show all text because your height was 150.

Comment: OMG - Thank you!  It just  *looked* like it wasn't working, but it was.

Answer (score 1):

We have checked the reported issue with the provided details on our end and reproduced it. To determine the width and height of the text to be drawn, we can use the measureString method in PdfFont. We have modified the code and attached the code snippet for your reference.

```
    // Create a PDF document.
PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();
PdfStandardFont standardFont=PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.helvetica, 20);
Size fontSize=standardFont.measureString(reportTitle);
// Add a page and draw text
document.pages.add().graphics.drawString(
   reportTitle,
   standardFont,
   brush: PdfSolidBrush(PdfColor(0, 0, 0)),
   bounds:  Rect.fromLTWH(20, 60, fontSize.width, fontSize.height));
```

Please find the UG documentation for further details
[Text drawing in Flutter PDF library | Syncfusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf/working-with-text#measuring-a-string)

Note: I work for Syncfusion.